# Changing Div content based on Geo IP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I currently have a website that is showing a price for a product within a <div>. I would like this number to change if the user is from outside the UK, for example changing the price to Euros rather than GBP.

Is this possible? I can't find an example I understand.

Comment: U have to tried write code by yourself, and only then show us your code, errors and ask for help

Comment: Yes, is possible. You can read this tutorial and try to implement: http://www.adammcfarland.com/2009/11/19/simple-ip-geolocation-using-javascript-and-the-google-ajax-search-api/

Answer (score -1):

You should give more example info but Im not going to be so critical.

You could capture the location using google maps if they agree to it, or ip address and then set a class to all the price divs and price symbol divs.

try something like this

```
   <div id="parent_id">
         <div class="item">
                <span class="symbol">£</span> <div class="price_divs" id="div1">5.00</div>
         </div>
         <div class="item">
                <span class="symbol">£</span> <div class="price_divs" id="div2">5.00</div>
         </div>
         <div class="item">
                <span class="symbol">£</span> <div class="price_divs" id="div3">5.00</div>
         </div>
  </div>


     <script>

   jQuery(function(){   ///requires jquery

        if(location == "US"){   //location must be a global variable given a value from google maps

       var all_pricing = $('#parent_id').find('.price_divs');

          $('.symbol').html('$');

          $.each(all_pricing,function(x,y){

                var c = convertToDollars($('#'+y.id).html());
                $('#'+y.id).html(c);

          });

        }

        function convertToDollars(cost)
        {

            ///some conversion here
            return cost;

        }


     });

      </script>
```

Comment: anyone want to explain why this was voted down? Thats cool though ;)